# How to identify a newly created autopartition in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I am new to oracle database. I am using database version 12.1.0.2. I have enabled auto list partition creation for a table. Whenever a new city is inserted to a column in the table, a new partition is created automatically. Is there any way to identify the new partition creation immediately using any dictionary view? I need to know either a script idea or procedure to immediately identify the newly created partition on the table and notify via email.

Below is an example of the partitions which are created for every new state inserted into column `SALES_STATE`:

```
SQL> desc sales_auto_list
 Name                                                                                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SALESMAN_ID                                                                                               NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 SALESMAN_NAME                                                                                              VARCHAR2(30)
 SALES_STATE                                                                                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 SALES_AMOUNT                                                                                               NUMBER(10)
 SALES_DATE                                                                                                NOT NULL DATE
```

New partitions created for each new row inserted

```
SQL> select table_name,partition_name,high_value from dba_tab_partitions where table_name ='SALES_AUTO_LIST';

TABLE_NAME           PARTITION_NAME       HIGH_VALUE
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
SALES_AUTO_LIST      P_CAL                'california'
SALES_AUTO_LIST      SYS_P801             'FLORIDA'
SALES_AUTO_LIST      SYS_P802             'MICHIGAN'
SALES_AUTO_LIST      SYS_P803             'CALIFORNIA'
SALES_AUTO_LIST      SYS_P804             'OREGON'
```

Total partition count

```
SQL> SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITIONING_TYPE, AUTOLIST, PARTITION_COUNT FROM USER_PART_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='SALES_AUTO_LIST';

TABLE_NAME           PARTITION AUT PARTITION_COUNT
-------------------- --------- --- ---------------
SALES_AUTO_LIST      LIST      YES              5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this.

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE regexp_like(partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')  AND
 TABLE_NAME = 
< your TableName> AND
table_name not like 'BIN$%'
```